# How do linux groups permit running specific commands bypassing file permissions and sudo

Tags: linux, permissions

Take for example docker. Once we install docker, we have the option of using sudo for every docker command, or add the user to the "docker" group and that user can run all docker commands. (I understand the severe security implications of adding users to the docker group, but please ignore that aspect as it is irrelevant to my question).

So, once the user is added to the "docker" group, the user is able to run all docker commands directly, like "docker ps", "docker images" etc (without sudo). Through the docker process, the user is able to read & write files that are apparently owned by root, for example /var/lib/docker & /etc/docker/daemon.json etc.

How was all this possible by merely adding a user to a group? Where can one view/modify what the group membership allows and disallows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker` command doesn't really *do* anything on its own. Its only job is to contact the "dockerd" system service (daemon) and ask it to do the operations on your behalf. And because the service runs as the 'root' user, it can access any files that root is allowed to access, and then give the results back to you.

There is no central place or list that allows such things based on group membership; each service enforces this on its own, and often slightly differently. For example, Docker uses the group to allow you to *connect* to the daemon at `/run/docker.sock` (note how this socket only grants permissions to root:docker).

Some other services instead allow anyone to connect, but verify group membership upon receiving a command. (For example, `systemctl` also does nothing else but forward your commands over to systemd – and systemd allows unprivileged users to issue some commands but refuses others.)

Comment: Thank you. 


So I guess my question would be, how does docker use the docker group to allow access to connect to the docker socket? 

Is this enforced in the docker code somewhere? 

And does such a model work only when you have a daemon running as a superuser on the system?

Comment: At first, the connection itself is enforced using file permissions, as the socket (whose path I've already given) is a "local" socket that behaves a lot like a file. It doesn't seem like Docker adds anything on top of that, because all commands have the same policy and so socket permissions are enough. However, the same thing is indeed enforced in code by many _other_ daemons – they use SO_PEERCRED or SCM_CREDENTIALS in order to know which user tried to connect and what their group memberships are. (systemd, dbus-daemon, openldap/slapd are a few I could name.)